# Google In-App Billing in Eclipse error of IabHelper cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, eclipse, in-app-billing

I've been trying to implement Google In-App Billing into one of my Android apps by following http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample
but I get the error that "IabHelper cannot be resolved to a type" after following the steps for an "Existing Project". I've added a picture as well. [image]

Comment: Did you do step 3? "Add the helper classes from the /util directory of the TrivialDrive sample to your project. Remember to change the package name declarations in those files accordingly so that your project compiles correctly."

Comment: yes. I believe I have a package for that, which I imported it with the Base64 classes, but still no solution.

Comment: I copied 9 classes from `com.example.android.trivialdrivesample.util` to my project. `IabHelper` is one of them and is what your code should resolve to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you have followed **step 3**:

> Add the helper classes from the /util directory of the TrivialDrive sample to your project. Remember to change the package name declarations in those files accordingly so that your project compiles correctly.

You need to copy all the classes under `com.example.android.trivialdrivesample.util` and put them in your project. `IabHelper` is one of them and seems to be what you are missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

so this worked for me:

If you just copied the files, then you need to change the package name of each java file in the util folder...

Answer (score 0):

I have misunderstood where to copy the helper classes to? I am not able to read that from images provided. I have all of them changed accordingly to my app however still struggling on where to copy these files to. Neither able to understand that from https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#SetPermission as I do not have util folder in my app.